# Resolve Angular circular module dependencies and components(parent-child)

Tags: angular, typescript, module, parent-child, circular-dependency

I have the following structure

```
Project
---Module1
------ComponentA
------componentB
---Module2
------componentC
------componentD
```

in the imports of the `Module1.module.ts` I'm doing an import of the Module2 because in the `componentA` I'm using the `componentC` belongs to the `Module2`.

Now, I need to use the `componentB(Module1)` in my `componentD` belongs to the module2 but I have a lot of errors because I'm creating a circular dependencies when I import the `Module1` in my `Module2.module.ts`

The structure in this moment is: `Module1` is parent of `Module2`. So, I don't know if exists some way to access to one component that belongs to the `Module1(parent)` from one component in `Module2(Child)`

Comment: My answer would be to reconsider if Component B should be a child of module 1. If it is needed in module 2 and module 2 is a child module of module 1, it does not belong there. Circular dependencies reveal a problem in your design, and make it clear when things need to be reconsidered.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the current module structure you could create a third module for components B and C - you would import `module 3` into `module 1` and `module 2`.

```
Project
---Module1
------ComponentA
---Module2
------componentD
---Module3
------componentC
------componentB
```